# Is there a better word for "fit in"?

Tags: synonyms

What i wan't to say is "we can't **fit in X in the modern world**"

but it doesn't portrays the correct meaning what i mean is that its wrong to mould X according to the parameters of the modern world, is there a better word than "Fit in"

Comment: _"we can't fit X into the modern world"_ is closer to your meaning but what's wrong with saying "its wrong to mould X according to the parameters of the modern world" as you did in the question?

Comment: it's just not suitable for the context, i don't wan't it to be too long

Comment: What is X? It would seem relevant to the question.

Comment: any idea or framework, like communism, socialism etc

Comment: Mix X in, blend X in, modify X by, place X in, cast X into, impress upon X, the modern world. Wouldn't any number of synonyms of mould, fit, bearing, fit in your context?

Comment: By the way, there's no such word as `wan't` - it's _want_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We can't make Communism/Socialism/Feudalism relevant to the modern world"...

If you want to restructure whatever you're writing, go with:

"[ideology] doesn't work in 2020" (or something). Then state your reasoning. If this is a political piece it's important to get your assumptions and reasoning out of the way up front, but simply and clearly (depending on your audience).